# Chaining Task Module MS Teams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am trying to chain task module to show a Custom Form after one another with a button click. I followed the documentation, but not exactly able to figure out how it's done. 
I am using bot framework 4.9 SDK
Here's my code:

Task/Fetch Function

```
 protected override async Task<TaskModuleResponse> OnTeamsTaskModuleFetchAsync(ITurnContext<IInvokeActivity> turnContext, TaskModuleRequest taskModuleRequest, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

       //*** Returning first custom form****//
        return new TaskModuleResponse
        {
            Task = new TaskModuleContinueResponse
            {
                Type = "continue",
                Value = await this.GetTaskInfo(turnContext,JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TaskFetchJsonSerializer>(taskModuleRequest.Data.ToString()).data)
            },
        };
    }
```

Task/Submit:

```
protected override async Task<TaskModuleResponse> OnTeamsTaskModuleSubmitAsync(ITurnContext<IInvokeActivity> turnContext, TaskModuleRequest taskModuleRequest, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {              
           //***sending second custom form as continue response***//
        return new TaskModuleResponse
        {
            Task = new TaskModuleContinueResponse
            {
                Type = "continue",
                Value = await this.GetTaskInfo(turnContext, TaskModuleIds.PRFPAddressForm)
            },
        }};
```

I am able to render the first form, but after a button click the second form doesn't render.

Comment: You need to set up action for task module chaining, if you want to call task module within task module. Could you please tell me where you are implementing task module is it in bot, tab or message extension?

Comment: Thanks for quick help. It's in bot , I am using TeamsActivityHandler. Trinetra-MSFT.

Comment: Is there any sample for setting up action for chaining in custom from? :( In this scenario there is one button(on which I need to add action) in previous custom form which on click will redirect to other task module. I tried to search online for samples but couldn't get proper reference for this.

Comment: You need to pass data in when you call submitTask in your first task module. when you click on task module button. your bot will receive a inoke message task/fetch or task/submit their you can create a new task module response with html form or adaptive card

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code for invoking task module within task module

**HTML Page to invoke from Task Module**

```
<html>
    <body>
    <button type="button" id=""taskModuleChaining" onClick="OpenAnotherTaskModule()">Open Another Task Module</button>
    </body>
    <script>
    microsoftTeams.initialize();

    function OpenAnotherTaskModule(){
    let taskInfo={
    action:"newTaskModule"
    }
    taskInfo.height="medium";
    taskInfo.width="medium";
    microsoftTeams.tasks.submitTask(taskInfo);
return true;
    }
    </script>
    </html>
```

**Bot code in c#:**

```
 {
    //serialize the task module submit data in a model to get the action name
    string action =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.TaskModuleActionData<string>>(activityValue).Data;

                if (action=="newTaskModule")
                {
 var response = new TaskModuleResponse
            {
                Task = new TaskModuleContinueResponse
                {
                    Value = new TaskModuleTaskInfo()
                    {
                        url= "yourngrok.io",
                        Height = 200,
                        Width = 400,
                        Title = "Task Module",
                    },
                },
            };
return response;

    }
            }
```

Your bot will receive a invoke message. You can parse the data sent by task module to your bot in a model later you can create task module response and return it.

Comment: Thanks @Trinetra-MSFT

Comment: Just Curious, Why are we setting "taskInfo.height="medium;" into .cshtml page above?, when we are sending Height =200 while building TAskModuleTaskInfo Object in Task/Fetch or Task/Submit above? @Trinetra-MSFT